# Хранение бд в папке с программой

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

Появилась необходимость переносной проги, без использования Managment Studio. Вроде как создал локальную бд с типом .mdf, лежит в папке с программой. Но не работает на других компьютерах. Также я подключил Entity Framework, может в этом проблема. Пробовал и так и так (см. скриншоты)
[image: Вариант 1]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Managment Studio - это просто инструмент для подключения к серверу.

Сам сервер надо ставить отдельно, как полноценный SQL Server, так и localdb.

Т.е. для подключения файлов через AttachDbFilename вам все равно нужно предварительно установить минимум SQL Server Express / LocalDB.

Если вам нужна полностью переносимая база данных, без необходимости предварительной установки - переходите на SQL Server Compact или SQLite.

Comment: Будет ли отличаться принцип работы с entity framework, например на Compact