# Скомпилированное приложение winforms не видит БД

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, sql-server, sql-server-localdb

У меня есть приложение, которое отображает таблицы из БД. База данных находится в папке с проектом, соответственно, строка подключения выглядит так

```
string connectString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=E:\Projects\csharp\MonitoringUUD\MonitoringUUD\MonitoringUUD.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

При сборке проекта база данных присутствует в папке с приложением. При запуске скомпилированного приложение на ПК с папкой проекта всё работает отлично, но как только пытаюсь запустить на другом пк - ошибка подключения к sql. Предполагаю, что проблема в строке подключения. Как можно исправить, чтобы программа считывала данные из бд из папки с приложением?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Хранение бд в папке с программой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/834753/%d0%a5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9)

Comment: Или этого: [C# MSSQL Что необходимо для запуска?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/603435/c-mssql-%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0)